# In R shiny, how to incorporate scrolling into modal dialog box?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, dt

In running the below MWE code, and as shown in image at bottom, user inputs into the matrix rendered in modal dialog result in matrix compression. The more columns the user inputs into the matrix, the more the matrix compresses, until you're left with a difficult-to-read matrix.

Is there a way to not allow the matrix to compress as columns are added but instead extend right, with the user using a scrollbar to navigate left/right? I've been trying to insert scrollbars this morning without luck yet.

Perhaps the challenge lies with `shinyMatrix` package itself. I wonder if DT Table can be used since it presents nicely (with scrolling), with `shinyMatrix` serving as its back-end engine for input/output? Package `rhandsontable`, though pretty, doesn't work well in modal dialog.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("show2nd","Show 2nd input (in modal)")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      matrixInput("input1", 
        value = matrix(c(10,5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),c("X|Y",""))),
        rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
        cols =  list(extend = FALSE, 
                     delta = 1,
                     delete = FALSE,
                     names = TRUE, 
                     editableNames = FALSE,
                     multiheader=TRUE),
        class = "numeric"),
      helpText("Generate curves (X|Y):"),
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$show2nd,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        matrixInput("input2", 
          value = if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2} else
                  {matrix(c(input$input1[1,1],input$input1[1,2]), 1, 2, 
                          dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),c("X|Y","")))},
          rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
          cols =  list(extend = TRUE, 
                       delta = 2,
                       delete = TRUE,
                       names = TRUE, 
                       editableNames = FALSE,
                       multiheader=TRUE
                       ),
          class = "numeric"),
    footer = modalButton("Close")
    ))
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else 
            {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10),ylab = "y")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Adding images to show scrolling for modal inputs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `modalDialog` gained a `size` argument in shiny 1.7. Did you try `size = "xl"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach using `library(shinyjs)`:

I wrapped the `matrixInput` in a `div` with `style = "overflow-x: auto;"`.

When columns are added to the matrix input2's width is restyled reactively via `runjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("show2nd","Show 2nd input (in modal)")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      matrixInput("input1", 
                  value = matrix(c(10,5), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),c("X|Y",""))),
                  rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
                  cols =  list(extend = FALSE, 
                               delta = 1,
                               delete = FALSE,
                               names = TRUE, 
                               editableNames = FALSE,
                               multiheader=TRUE),
                  class = "numeric"),
      helpText("Generate curves (X|Y):"),
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$show2nd,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        div(matrixInput("input2", 
                        value = if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2} else
                        {matrix(c(input$input1[1,1],input$input1[1,2]), 1, 2, 
                                dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),c("X|Y","")))},
                        rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
                        cols =  list(extend = TRUE, 
                                     delta = 2,
                                     delete = TRUE,
                                     names = TRUE, 
                                     editableNames = FALSE,
                                     multiheader=TRUE
                        ),
                        class = "numeric"), style = "overflow-x: auto;", id = "container"),
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$show2nd, input$input2), {
    print(paste0('$("#input2").css("width","calc(100% + ', (dim(input$input2)[2]-2 + dim(input$input2)[2]%%2)*115, 'px")'))
    runjs(paste0('$("#input2").css("width","calc(100% + ', (dim(input$input2)[2]-2 + dim(input$input2)[2]%%2)*115, 'px")'))
    runjs("document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 1000;")
    # runjs("$('#container').scrollLeft(1000)")
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else 
    {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10),ylab = "y")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: All I can say for now is ummm, wow.... that is beautiful...I was doubting there even was a solution

Comment: When I input into the matrix in the modal dialog, the scrolling works great. I scroll to the right as the matrix expands from my inputs. However if I close the modal and reopen it, it pops up (carrying the values last entered, as it should) compressed and not with the cursor as it had before when inputting. Is there a way to have it re-rendered with the scrolling (and uncompressed), the way it appears when inputting?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to the question? I'm not sure what you are referring to. Can't look into it right now - I'm on mobile.

Comment: OK, I'll add the images to the original question. First image shows me inputting out to column group 8 (all 1's). Then I close the modal, and when I reopen it, all my insertions from image 1 reappear as they should, but now compressed with no cursor.

Comment: Ah I see - we need to check the column count after opening the modal.  The observer is now also listening on `input$show2nd` please check my edit.

Comment: Added another `runjs` call to auto scroll to the right after updating the input (`scrollLeft`).

Comment: Yes, I see, that works. What is the line of commented-out code, "# runjs("$('#container').scrollLeft(1000)")," for when activated?

Comment: Forgot to delete it. Just another way to use scrollLeft.

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal. This is very useful. Is there a way to freeze that left-most column of the table/matrix rendered inside the modal dialog? So that the user can see the row headers as the table/matrix expands to the right. I've been fiddling with shinyjs(), no luck yet, but there has to be a simple way to do this, seems kind of basic but then again I know nothing about js/css/html

Comment: Btw I posted a simpler example last night as a new question